# How to include other .gradle files depending on the product flavors and buildtypes

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

In the main `build.gradle` I have

```
android {
    ……

    defaultConfig {
         ……
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {……}
        release {……}
    }

    productFlavors {
        lite {
            apply from: 'lite_api_config.gradle'
             ……
        }
        pro {
            apply from: 'pro_api_config.gradle'
             ……
        }
    }
}
```

**lite_api_config.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField('String', 'url', '"https://lite.com/"')
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField('String', 'url', '"https://debug.lite.com/"')
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField('String', 'url', '"https://release.lite.com/"')
        }
    }
}
```

**pro_api_config.gradle**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField('String', 'url', '"https://pro.com/"')
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField('String', 'url', '"https://debug.pro.com/"')
        }

        release {
            buildConfigField('String', 'url', '"https://release.pro.com/"')
        }
    }
}
```

But when I build this, using a build variant of `liteDebug`, in the `BuildConfig.url` I get "https://debug.pro.com/", which is wrong and looks like both the child gradle files are included somehow

Is it even possible to have separate files for different product flavors and include them in the `build.gradle` based on which flavor is being built.

Comment: Where did you put your **lite_api_config.gradle** & **pro_api_config.gradle** files, is it at the same level where app level **build.gradle** is?

Comment: @JeelVankhede Yes same level where `build.gradle` is

Comment: Will get back to you once I find the solution, right now I'm in middle of it.